# Search result is case sensitive for German umlauts with utf8_general_ci collation and utf8 character-set-server

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

In MySQL 5.5,Search result is case sensitive for German umlauts with utf8_general_ci collation and utf8 character-set-server.I have 2 values in my Database table say öder and Öder.When I run a query to search for the strings using the keyword 'Öder',only Öder is retrieved as the search result and the value starting with ö i.e 'örder' is not retrieved.If I change the character-set-server to latin1 in my.cnf file of MySQL server and collation to latin1_general_ci(Same charset and collation change to latin1 I did for the corresponding Database and table also),it works fine i.e both values are retrieved as search result.But is there a way to achieve case-insensitve search for German umlauts using utf8 as the character-set-server?Facing this issue for other words starting with and containing othe german umlauts like ü,Ü,ä,Ä as well.

Comment: No collation will treat `'örder` = `öder` -- was that a typo?  Further, please clarify whether you do or do not want `öder` to match `oder` -- that is accent stripping, independent of case folding.

Comment: If I search with Ö the word starting with ö is not retrieved.I am not concerned as whether order is matched or not.I am dealing with only Öder and örder.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysql commandline tool to test things:

```
mysql> SELECT 'Ö' = 'ö' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
+-------------------------------------+
| 'Ö' = 'ö' COLLATE utf8_general_ci   |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

`1` means `true`; `0` means `false`.

Any of the `utf8_..._ci` collations will treat a bunch of accented / not-accented, uppercase / lowercase characters as equal.  For example, utf8mb4_german2_ci says these are equal:  `O=o=º=Ò=Ó=Ô=Õ=ò=ó=ô=õ` and sort before `oe=Ö=ö=Œ=œ`.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) is a rundown on where most letters stand in most utf8 collations.

For most usage, _general_ci is not as good as _unicode_ci, which is not as good as _unicode_520_ci, which will be superseded by a Unicode 9.0 standard in MySQL 8.0.

I think *german2* is aimed at "phone book" collation.  But maybe not.  In 8.0, `utf8mb4_german2_ci` collates `D=d=Ď=ď < Dž=dz=dž < Ð=ð`.  But `utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci` has `D=d=Ð=ð=Ď=ď < Dž=dz=dž`.  More details [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) .